# keras model.evaluate doens't seem to be using weights

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to build a CNN and I'm using keras for the classification.

During the training step (model.fit()), I get accuracy near 90% but even using the same data on the test (model.evaluate()) I get roughly 50%.

I think that it should not happen, as I'm using data that the model has already seen. Here is my code using the same data for train and test:

```
classificationModel.fit(X_train_img, Y_train_img, epochs=20, batch_size=50)
print('\nevaluating\n')
preds = classificationModel.evaluate(X_train_img, Y_train_img, batch_size=50)

print ("Loss = " + str(preds[0]))
print ("Test Accuracy = " + str(preds[1]))
```

and here is the output:

```
...
Epoch 17/20
6/6 [==============================] - 0s 25ms/step - loss: 0.0145 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 18/20
6/6 [==============================] - 0s 24ms/step - loss: 0.0135 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 19/20
6/6 [==============================] - 0s 24ms/step - loss: 0.0132 - accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 20/20
6/6 [==============================] - 0s 24ms/step - loss: 0.0136 - accuracy: 1.0000

evaluating

6/6 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step - loss: 7.6774 - accuracy: 0.4800

Loss = 7.677433490753174
Test Accuracy = 0.47999998927116394
```

in this case, shouldn't the model return something like 95~100% accuracy?

Comment: its suspicious that the model reaches 100% accuracy, how many classes are in your data and what is their distribution?

Comment: if you have used normalization on your train data then you should aslo use that normalization on your test data.

Comment: @Ach113 in this example, I used 50 150*150*1 images, it's reaching 100% accuracy because I'm overfitting on purpose, only to show that even using this same data on evaluating it reaches 50% accuracy, you can see that I've used X_train_image and Y_train_image on train and test

Comment: @yakhyo as you can see on the code snippet, I've called evaluate right after fit, it's the same data on train and test